# How to implement multiple kernels in LIBSVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I wish to improve the accuracy of my SVM classification results by using multiple kernel learning (eg., RBF & Poly). Are there any resources to help me figure out how to implement this in LIBSVM? The resources I have searched for show uniquely MKL results, which I don't need.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Train two different models with different kernels and compare them? Can you also elaborate on the resources you have found?

Comment: I want to implement something like [this](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/cel-01003007/file/Lecture9_Multi_Kernel_SVM.pdf). Here, 2 different kernels have been simultaneously implemented.

Comment: That is interesting but I am afraid that given the amount of work to make that happen within LIBSVM it would be worth it to just implement your own solution from scratch. The link you sent describes a change in the underlaying optimization problem (to adjust each dm). What's the motivation of doing this in LIBSVM instead of using another implementation?

Comment: I have found SVM with RBF kernel to be the most suitable classifier for my problem. But now I want to increase the accuracy, and I can do it three ways: 1) optimize the parameters using GA, or PSO; 2) multiple kernel SVM; 3) parallelization. The last is a long term objective. Right now I want to make a comparative study of the first two. FYI, I am a beginner student in ML.